# Best way to Store and Count available stock (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am not sure how to proceed with counting the stock and storing the stock in generated invoices.

**Live data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20ff4/4**

Table `articles` there the static product info is stored:

```
create table articles
(
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint proxies_pk
            primary key,
    prod_article_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    prod_article_pub_id serial not null,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    cat integer,
    prod_brand_id integer,
    barcode bigint,
    supplier_code varchar
);
```

This table opens a document, and defines the type of document:

```
create table documents
(
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint documents_pk
            primary key,
    sale_doc_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    sale_doc_alpha varchar,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    sale_type_id integer not null,
    frozen boolean default false
);

create table types
(
    sale_type_id serial not null
        constraint types_pk
            primary key,
    name varchar,
    draft boolean default false
);
```

Where each artricle is added as an item of the document:

```
create table items
(
    sale_unit_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint units_pk
            primary key,
    sale_unit_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) not null
);
```

These are the available products in the warehouse:

```
create table products
(
    whse_prod_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null,
    whse_prod_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    t_created timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) default 1,
    global_ctry_id integer
);
```

---

I am trying to query this like so:

```
SELECT
     (sum(products.quantity) - COALESCE(_items.quantity, 0)) as quantity
     ,articles.prod_article_pub_id as article

 FROM products

 LEFT JOIN articles ON products.prod_article_pvt_uuid = articles.prod_article_pvt_uuid

 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.prod_article_pvt_uuid)
         items.prod_article_pvt_uuid
         ,items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
         ,sum(items.quantity) as quantity
     FROM items
     LEFT JOIN documents ON items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid = documents.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
     LEFT JOIN types ON documents.sale_type_id = types.sale_type_id
     WHERE
         items.archived = false
     AND documents.archived = false
     AND types.draft = false
     GROUP BY
         items.prod_article_pvt_uuid
         ,items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
 ) AS _items ON _items.prod_article_pvt_uuid = products.prod_article_pvt_uuid


 GROUP BY
     articles.prod_article_pub_id
     ,_items.quantity

 ORDER BY
     article ASC,
     quantity DESC
```

It does give me the desired result. But I am wondering if this is the correct way at going about it, cause it looks like it might struggle with millions of rows.

Basically each time I need to display the quantity available in stock I have to count every single document ever generated.

Will it be a performance bottle neck with millions of rows?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! You might be in danger of reinventing the wheel? Take a look [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) (search for "retail"). Also, search for "Open Source retail software" - there's lots of stuff out there - you may be able to use and/or adapt one of those systems to your needs? I'm not saying "don't do it" - I would however spend some time looking around before committing to a large project. Best of luck!

Comment: @Vérace I've explored that option too. However they were missing features that we needed.

Comment: Grand - you know what you want - that's a good first step! I hope the project works out for you - it's a big undertaking!